# Finding a value of a scalar making two independent vectors perpendicular

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a real inner product space. If $u,v$ are linearly independent in $V$ prove there is only one possible value for a scalar $\alpha$ such that $v$ is orthogonal to $u-\alpha v$.

My idea: We need their inner product to be zero. As such we have $\langle v,u-\alpha v\rangle=0$. By linearity this gives $\langle v,u\rangle-\alpha\langle v,v\rangle=0$. Rearranging we have $\alpha=\frac{\langle v,u\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}$, on assumption $v\ne 0$. This gives a unique expression for $\alpha$ as claimed. Is this right?

Comment: Suppose you also had $\langle v, u - \beta v\rangle = 0.$ Can you reach a contradiction from here? (use linearity of the second argument)

Comment: Your method is different than what I was going to hint towards but it is correct, noting that if $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent then $v$ cannot be zero.

Comment: Correct, since $v,u$ are independent then non of them is zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly valid, and in fact a stronger result than the one I was leading towards, but I still thought it might be nice to post my proof idea.

Consider for contradiction that for some linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$ in $V$ we had that there were distinct real values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\langle v, u-\alpha v\rangle = 0$ and $\langle v, u-\beta v\rangle = 0.$

We clearly have $\langle v, u-\alpha v\rangle - \langle v, u-\beta v\rangle = 0,$ and by the linearity of the inner product we can rewrite this as $\langle v, (\beta - \alpha)v\rangle = (\beta - \alpha)\langle v, v\rangle = 0.$ Because we defined $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as distinct, we can divide both sides by $\beta - \alpha$ to obtain $\langle v, v\rangle = 0.$ However, because $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent we must have that $v \neq 0,$ so by the positive-definiteness of the inner product we must have $\langle v, v\rangle > 0,$ and we've reached a contradiction. So, we can conclude that there cannot exist any such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ meaning there can only be one such value with our desired property.

Again, your process provides a stronger result because it both proves that there is exactly one satisfying value of $\alpha,$ and actually constructs the required value of $\alpha,$ whereas my proof only proves that there is *at most* one such value. Still, I thought this proof was fun and interesting, and I thought you'd like to see it.

Comment: Thanks! I really like your proof ; it is very neat indeed

Comment: It should be said that what is asked here is the classical **Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process** !